# What is the correct result for this query?

Tags: aggregate, sql-standard

I came across this puzzle [in the comments here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/06/04/Katmai_3A00_-T_2D00_SQL-Grouping-sets.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE r (b INT);

SELECT 1 FROM r HAVING 1=1;
```

[SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f80e/1) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3f80e/1) return 1 row.

[MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f80e/1) and [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f80e/1) return zero rows.

Which is correct? Or are both equally valid?

Comment: Nice puzzle. I think the correct is to return 1 row. SQL-Server is contradicting itself though because `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r;` returns 1 row (with `0`), while `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r GROUP BY ();` returns no rows.

Comment: Want more? `SELECT 1 WHERE 1=0 HAVING 1=1;`. [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f80e/7) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3f80e/3) still return one row. [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f80e/15) wants FROM DUAL and returns no rows. MySQL doesn't compile neither [with FROM DUAL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f80e/4) nor [without it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f80e/3).

Comment: @ypercube: I'm still puzzled as to the reasons for this difference. But to be honest, I've already used `GROUP BY ()` as a way of adding the grand total only when there are details. Omitting `GROUP BY` would yield an extra row. Or I would have to use an `IF` (or a `WHERE EXISTS`, perhaps).

Comment: @AndriyM For some unknown reason "dual" and "HAVING" do not play well in MySQL. (Nice finding). But the equivalent works: `SELECT 1 AS t FROM (SELECT 1) tmp WHERE 1=0 HAVING 1=1;` [1-row-no-dual](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f80e/16) and returns 0 rows.

Comment: @SQLKiwi - What about this passage from the spec. "If TE does not immediately contain a `<group by clause>`, then `“GROUP BY ()”` is implicit.". Shouldn't both queries return the same results then?

Comment: @SQLKiwi - Ah OK thanks! (embarrassed to admit I googled Dr Emmett Brown expecting him to be some eminent database authority that I had never heard of but the penny has now dropped!  :-)

Comment: Oracle and SQL-Server agree on this: [SQL-fiddle: with and without `GROUP BY ()`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0471f/7)

Comment: But disagree on these (Oracle executes queries with `HAVING` differently): [SQl-fiddle 2: HAVING makes things different](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0471f/5)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per the standard:

```
SELECT 1 FROM r HAVING 1=1
```

means

```
SELECT 1 FROM r GROUP BY () HAVING 1=1
```

Citation ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011 7.10 Syntax Rule 1  (Part of the definition of the HAVING clause):

> Let `HC` be the `<having clause>`. Let `TE` be the `<table expression>` that
>   immediately contains `HC`. If `TE` does not immediately contain a
>   `<group by clause>`, then “`GROUP BY ()`” is implicit. Let `T` be the
>   descriptor of the table defined by the `<group by clause>` `GBC` immediately
>   contained in `TE` and let `R` be the result of `GBC`.

Ok so that much is pretty clear.

---

Assertion: `1=1` is true search condition. I will provide no citation for this.

---

Now

```
SELECT 1 FROM r GROUP BY () HAVING 1=1
```

is equivlent to

```
SELECT 1 FROM r GROUP BY ()
```

Citation ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011 7.10 General Rule 1:

> The `<search condition>` is evaluated for each group 
>   of `R`. The result of the `<having clause>` is a grouped
>   table of those groups of R for which the result of the
>   `<search condition>` is True.

Logic: Since the search condition is always true, the result is `R`, which is the result of the group by expression.

---

The following is an excerpt from the General Rules of 7.9 (the definition of the GROUP BY CLAUSE)

> 1) If no `<where clause>` is specified, then let `T` be the result of the preceding `<from clause>`; otherwise, let `T` be the result of the preceding `<where clause>`.
>
> 2) Case:
>
> a) If there are no grouping columns, then the result of
>   the `<group by clause>` is the grouped table consisting of `T` as its only group.

Thus we can conclude that

```
FROM r GROUP BY ()
```

results in a grouped table, consisting of one group, with zero rows (since R is empty).

---

An excerpt from the General Rules of 7.12, which defines a Query Specification (a.k.a a SELECT statement):

> 1) Case:
>
> a) If `T` is not a grouped table, then [...]
>
> b) If `T` is a grouped table, then
>
> Case:
>
> i) If `T` has 0 (zero) groups, then let TEMP be an empty table.
>
> ii) If `T` has one or more groups, then each `<value expression>` is applied
>   to each group of `T` yielding a table `TEMP` of `M` rows, where `M` is the
>   number of groups in `T`. The `i`-th column of TEMP contains the values
>   derived by the evaluation of the `i`-th `<value expression>`. [...]
>
> 2) Case:
>
> a) If the `<set quantifier>` `DISTINCT` is not specified, then the
>   result of the `<query specification>` is `TEMP`.

Therefore since the table has one group, it must have one result row.

Thus

```
SELECT 1 FROM r HAVING 1=1
```

should return a 1 row result set.

Q.E.D.

Comment: +1 Thanks for going to all that trouble! As @ypercube says SQL Server does seem to contradict itself here as SELECT 1 FROM r GROUP BY (); returns zero rows but the passage you quoted seems quite clear on this point.

Comment: May I ask where did you find the standard?  If you say 'on my bookshelf' I'll be disappointed :)

Comment: Technically I used the Final Draft International Standard, rather than the standard itself. Per ISO/IEC rules only editorial (non-technical) changes are permitted between FDIS and the final standard. The standard is spit up into multiple parts. [Part 1](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2153T-text_for_ballot-FDIS_9075-1.pdf), [Part 2](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2154T-text_for-ballot-FDIS_9075-2.pdf), [Part 4](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2155T-text_for_ballot-FDIS_9075-4.pdf) ...

Comment: [Part 11](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2156T-text_for_ballot-FDIS_9075-11.pdf), and [Part 14](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2157T-text_for_ballot-FDIS_9075-14.pdf).  Parts 3,9,10,and 13 Were not updated in 2011, and thus their previous versions apply. There is no part 12. Similarly there are no parts 5-8. See the [Wikipedia page for Sql:2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) or Part 1 itself for an explanation of what each part contains.

Answer (score 7):

When there is a `HAVING` clause, without a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 1 FROM r HAVING 1=1;
```

... then `GROUP BY ()` is implicit. So, the query should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT 1 FROM r GROUP BY () HAVING 1=1;
```

... which should group all rows of the table into one group (even if the table has no rows at all - it's still one group of 0 rows) and return 1 row. The `HAVING` with the `True` condition should have no effect at all after that.

---

From a different angle, how many rows should a query like this return?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(b) FROM r;
```

One, zero or "zero or one, depending on if the table is empty or not"?

I think one row, no matter how many rows `r` has.

Comment: Well the key issue is whether it's indeed true that "even if the table has no rows at all, it's still one group of 0 rows".  And the standard turns out to be explicit about this : "If there are no grouping columns, then ... is the grouped table consisting of T as its only group".  (and that holds even if T is empty - so there is indeed a group.)  Further on, the having clause specifies that the condition is applied to each group (in the example thus once).  They probably defined it this way to make SUM and COUNT return one row even for empty T's.

Comment: +1 (earlier!) Even though your logic is the same as Kevin's I've accepted his answer because of the quotations from the spec though. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith. Thnx. That I get from being lazy :)

Comment: @ypercube: +1 from me too. I decided to take the extra time to pull from the spec to prove that there was no weasel words hidden someplace that would make your answer wrong. But once I did that, I might as well post it as a full answer. So I did.

Comment: @Kevin: Well done. I hadn't spotted the *"... where M is the cardinality of T ..."* part yesterday.

Comment: @ypercube actually the phrase that mentions cardinality is for non-grouped rows. You want 1.b.ii which says *"where M is the number of groups in T."* I've trimmed down 1.b.i to hide irrelevant detail.

Comment: @ErwinSmout: Of course not. However this falls within fair use under US copyright law. Relatively small portions, quoted in the context of analysis (i.e. criticism) of the work, for educational purposes, with negligible impact on the work's ability to be sold.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see, it looks like SQLServer and PostgerSQL don't bother looking into table at all:

```
CREATE TABLE r (b INT);
insert into r(b) values (1);
insert into r(b) values (2);
SELECT 1 FROM r HAVING 1=1;
```

also returns just one row. Even though [SQLServer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) says

> When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.

that is not true in this case - `WHERE 1=1` instead of `HAVING` returns proper number of rows. I'd say it's optimizer bug (or at least documentation bug)... 
SQLServer plan shows 'Constant scan' in case of `HAVING` and 'table scan' for `WHERE`...

Oracle and Mysql behaviour seems more logical and correct to me...

Comment: You're right that SQL Server doesn't look at the table. The execution plan just has a constant scan and doesn't even reference the table. If it was only SQL Server I would have just put it down to a bug but as it isn't just SQL Server I'm wondering if there is some genuine ambiguity here.

Comment: PostgreSQL shows the same results as SQLServer, and as far as I can tell from output of `explain` "Result( rows=1 )..." for having and "Seq Scan " for "WHERE" it also doesn't look into the table... I guess it's somehow related to the fact that "FROM" is not mandatory in TSQL and PostgreSQL. I know Mysql also doesn't require it, but since they support `dual`, they probably parse the query a bit different. I agree, it sounds like a speculation, but I hope it makes some sense.