# Use of HAVING without GROUP BY in SQL queries

Tags: aggregate

In order to use `HAVING` in SQL queries , must there be a `GROUP BY` to aggregate the column names?

Are there any special cases where it is possible to use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` in SQL queries?

Must they co-exist at the same time?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No.

They don't have to coexist, as proved by the fact that the following query in Oracle works:

```
select * from dual having 1 = 1;
```

Similarly, in PostgreSQL the following query works:

```
select 1 having 1 = 1;
```

So `having` **doesn't** *require* `group by`.

Having is **applied** *after* the aggregation phase and must be used if you want to filter aggregate results. So the reverse isn't true, and the following won't work:

```
select a, count(*) as c
from mytable
group by a
where c > 1;
```

You need to replace `where` with `having` in this case, as follows:

```
select a, count(*) as c
from mytable
group by a
having c > 1;
```

NB The following query form will also work:

```
select *
from (
  select a, count(*) as c
  from mytable
  group by a
)
where c > 1;
```

You can see that using `having` is simply a shorthand version of this last query.

---

In summary, `having` is applied *after* the `group by` phase whereas `where` is applied *before* the `group by` phase.

Comment: Another example: `SELECT MIN(a) AS mina, MAX(a) As maxa FROM mytable HAVING MIN(a) < MAX(a);`

Comment: Yes. And PostgreSQL allows the following construct `select 1 having count(*) = 1;` which I have yet to grasp.

Comment: SQL Server allows too, `SELECT 1 AS id, 'Colin' AS name;` while others like Oracle have a special `dual` table. I don't think that either of these syntaxes is ANSI/ISO SQL (which requires `FROM`).

Comment: I didn't mean the lack of `from` but the reference to `count(*)` in the `having` clause without any indication as to over which columns this is being aggregated. Presumably it aggregates over all columns in the `select` clause.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, I agree that that's what it does (aggregate over all rows you mean - over all rows of an empty table).

Comment: Related question: [What is the correct result for this query?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33760/what-is-the-correct-result-for-this-query)

Comment: But `select * from foo having id = 1` would **not** work.

Answer (score 7):

Having is used to filter groups .

where clause is used to filter rows.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/

Comment: Your first statement is not correct. `having` is *applied* after the aggregation phase so *can be used to* filter groups.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of GROUP BY clause the query considers the whole relation as one group.

e.g.

```
     select count(*)
     from dual
     having count(*) > 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

HAVING is filtering the groups.
If you have not GROUP BY cause, all rows presents one group.
So, if predicate in HAVING evaluates as true, you get one row, otherwise no rows.